# REACT - using localstorage for updating a component

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

How to update a component by changing localstorage from another component?
for example with react hooks I want to call a function by changing localstorage value, but doesn't work:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        //call a function by changing id value in localstorage
    }, [localStorage.getItem("id")])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use ContextProvider to share same hooks and data between different components.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyContext = React.createContext();

const useMyHookEffect = (initId) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(initId);
  const saveId = (id) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('id', id);
    setId(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //Now you can get the id from the localStorage
    const myId = window.localStorage.getItem('id');
    setId(myId);
  }, []);

  return { id, saveId };
};

// Provider component that wraps app and makes themeMode object
export function MyHookProvider({ children, id }) {
  const myEffect = useMyHookEffect(id);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={myEffect}>
        {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

MyHookProvider.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
  id: null,
};

MyHookProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  id: PropTypes.string,
};

export const useMyHook = () => useContext(MyContext);
```

And you need to call it as provider outside of your components.

```
<MyHookProvider>
  <ComponentA />
  <ComponentB />
</MyHookProvider>
```

Now you can use shared hook between your components.

```
export function ComponentA(){
  const { id, saveId } = useMyHook(null);
  return (<div>{id}<button onClick={() => saveId(2)}></button></div>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to send a value from outside of react to a react component. How to set _id_in context outside of react?

Comment: You can export the functions from your hook. I have updated it. @s.d.fard

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.addEventListener('storage ...`

---

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
       function example() {
        //call a function by changing id value in localstorage
       }
       window.addEventListener('storage', example) 
       return () =>  window.removeEventListener('storage', example) 
      } , [ ])
```

---

inside `example` you might check that `id` is the `localStorage` piece make the function run

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work for me `React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('storage',(e)=>console.log("EVENT FIRED"))
    }, [])`

Comment: you can try instead `window.onstorage = () =>`, though its weird cause your code looks like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Answer (score -3):

As you want to re-render an element you should use states. By using states every element using this variable will automatically update. You can use the hook useState().

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [ id, setId ] = useState(initalValue);

useEffect(() => {
    setId(localStorage.getItem('id'));
}, [localStorage.getItem('id')]);

return(
    'Your code and the element that should update'
);
```